# Problema en la cabecera(HTTP Header Manager) Jmeter con ":"

Tags: http, cabeceras-http, pruebas-unitarias

Actualmente estoy intentando hacer pruebas de carga con `Jmeter` bajo `https`.

En la parte de "HTTP Header Manager" o "Gestor de Cabecera HTTP", introduzco una variable `${foo}` y su valor "foo" contiene `":"` en una de sus partes.

Sé que es algo reservado para separar parámetros en el header.

¿Habría alguna forma de escapar de los dos puntos `":"`?

<sub>La versión de Jmeter es 3.2.</sub>

Comment: ¿Los `":"` están en el nombre del header o en el valor?

Comment: Vienen en el valor.

Comment: Según el [RFC2616 sec 4.2](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2), se permite cualquier separador dentro del valor, incluidos los `":"`. Incluso lo vemos comúnmente con headers como `Referer: https://es.stackoverflow.com` (que tienen los dos puntos dentro del valor).

Comment: Pues son los dos puntos. Interpreta que lo siguiente a los dos puntos es el siguiente parámetro y devuelve un error. He estado quitando los dos puntos y me responde como que ese valor {foo} es incorrecto, es una respuesta correcta ya que faltan esos dos puntos.